# Is it possible to stopPropagation to Browser Extension?

Tags: javascript, browser-extension, stoppropagation, lastpass

The LastPass Browser Extension is executing some code within a "mouseup" event which is slowing down my page when there are several thousand input elements (checkboxes) on the page.  I know, I know, but it is within a large tree control with checkboxes on each node of the tree.

I found someone talking about this on the LastPass forums here: https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=286955

However, since there has been no response from LastPass to that post, I was wondering if there is a way to stopPropagation of the event to LastPass to prevent it from going to them on the pages where I know it will cause a slowdown.

**Is there any way to intercept an event and stop it from propagating to a browser extension?**

I've tried adding an "onmouseup" handler and calling event.stopPropagation()  and event.stopImmediatePropagation(), but that doesnt seem to stop the browser extension from running its "mouseup" function.
Where this is happening, I have no need for the LastPass extension, and when I disable the extension, I do not experience the slowdown.

[image: LastPass profiler]
Here is a screenshot of Chrome's profiler showing a 757ms delay that is happening on *every mouseup!!*   Add to that jQuery's Sizzle selector delay of 267ms and its just painfully slow to navigate the tree control on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to close this out in case anyone comes here with the same question.

e.stopImmediatePropagation did work.    The problem I had with it not working related to event [Capturing vs Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).  The event I was trying to prevent was registered with useCapture=true.  In order for the stopImmediatePropagation to work, I had to also add my event with useCapture=true.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //this is to stop LastPass from listening to mouseup on my page
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }, true);
});
```

The good news here is that `click` events still fire even though I have stopped all handling of the `mouseup`.

Dont know why that eluded me...  hopefully it will help someone else as well.